# How to turn off printer ink saver mode?

Tags: windows-10, printer

My printer is running low on ink, and all the printed documents suddenly started looking faded; it seems that some kind of ink saver mode was activated.
Any idea if this behavior is happening on the level of hardware (HP 2130) or software? Is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: If the option exists it would be in the printer options (I.e in the same menu for portrait or landscape).

Comment: @Ramhound I couldn't find any so far, but maybe I was looking in wrong places.

Comment: I did say if it exists, if it doesn’t exist, it’s likely due to the low ink status.  You can verify if draft mode is on that could make the difference.  Unfortunately, many printers are way to smart for their good, and OEM printer software is notoriously horrible

Comment: Tip: Get the latest official drivers from the manufacturer for that specific model, and use those, as they'll often have specific options in there that aren't included in the generic Windows driver.

Comment: I still suggest checking the OEM driver for options to deal with this problem, even though as Ramhound correctly points out: the OEM software is often terrible for usual day-to-day operations. ;)

Comment: Make and model of printer?